# PCに接続されているキーボードの数と種類の取得について

Tags: c++, windows

PCに接続されているキーボードの数と種類を取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
ノートPCを使用している場合に、USBにてテンキー有りのキーボードが接続されたかどうかを
調べたいと思います。

`GetKeyboardType`を使ってみましたが、テンキー有りキーボードを接続しても、
接続しなくても結果は変わりませんでした。

環境はVisual C++です。

Comment: WMI の[Win32_Keyboard class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) を使ってクエリすればいいかと思います。

Comment: Win32_Keyboardクラスで情報を取得してみました。インストールされているキーボードの数は判りましたが、USBキーボードを抜いてもWin32_Keyboardで取得できる数は変わりませんでした。また、テンキーの有り・無しの判断ができませんでした。（ファンクションキーの数は取得できました。）

Comment: 「USBキーボードを抜いてもWin32_Keybo‌​ardで取得できる数は変わりませんでした」 これはおそらくタイミングの問題だと思います。「テンキーの有り・無し」は、キーボードの種類とはまた別だと思います。確か、テンキー部分とそうじゃない部分の数値キーなどはキーコードが違ったはずなので、それの違いを使って判別はできるかもしれません。

Comment: 「テンキー部分とそうじゃない部分の数値キーな‌​どはキーコードが違ったはずなので、それの違いを使って判別はできるかもしれません。 」 
テンキー有りのキーボードで、NumLockがONの時はテンキー特有のキーコードなのですが、NumLickがOFFの時にテンキーの「.（Del）」を押すと、テンキーではないDelキーと同じキーコードになってしまうため、判別できませんでした。 
テンキー有りのキーボードか無しのキーボードかの自動判断は難しいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

テンキー無しキーボードにとって、テンキー有りキーボードで単にテンキーが使われなかったことと大差ありません。また物理的に独立したテンキーが用意されていなくてもノートパソコンのように既存のキー部分にテンキーをマッピングされているものもあります。
ですので区別する機構は用意されていないと思われます。

本気で識別するのであればBLUEPIXYさんも提案されているようにWMIのWin32_Keyboardを使い、DeviceIDからキーボードの機種を判別することぐらいでしょうか。そうだとしてもやはりテンキーの有無は識別できないかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

USB-HID の規格上は、デバイスは Report Descriptor に使用するキーコードの一覧を返してくれるはずなので、そこに keypad〇〇 （テンキー）のコードが含まれるかどうかで判別できると思います。
ただ、Windows で任意のデバイスの Report Descriptor を取得する方法は、申し訳ないですが詳しく知りません。

Answer (score 0):

キーボードそのものの判別ではありませんが、
コメントにある NumKeyロックOff時のDeleteキーなどについては、拡張キーフラグも組み合わせて見れば区別できるんじゃないかと思います。

[WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx)

上記のbits 24のところです。

[GetKeyNameText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc364675.aspx)でもこのフラグを見ています。

ただし拡張キーフラグが 1の時がNumpadというわけではないのでそこは注意してください。
たとえばEnterであれば拡張キーフラグが 1のとき、NumpadのEnterですが、
DeleteキーはNumPadのDelが拡張キーフラグ 0になります。

一見するとSCANCODEでも判別できそうに見えますが、SCANCODEはOEM依存（キーボードメーカー依存）なので正確とは言えません。
（実際は 3種類くらいに落ち着くとは思いますが絶対ではないので）

以下はWM_KEYDOWNでタイトルバーにGetKeyNameTextや拡張キーフラグなどの内容を出力する VC++のサンプルです。

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        TCHAR buffer[256];
        TCHAR keyname[128];

        GetKeyNameText(lParam, keyname, sizeof(TCHAR) * 128);


        _stprintf_s(buffer, _T("%s , ext: %d vkey: %X scancode :%04X \0"),
            keyname, (lParam & 0x01000000) >> 24, wParam, (lParam & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);

        SetWindowText(hWnd, buffer);

        break;
```

Answer (score -1):

使ったことはありませんが、この辺りの情報が参考にならないでしょうか。

Keyboard and Mouse Input  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632585(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: 質問文にある[GetKeyboardType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724336.aspx)はそこに含まれるAPIです。PS/2向けでたいした識別ができないというのが質問の発端と思われます。